# strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, libraries

I just started to use Ubuntu. I installed the 12.04 64bit Ubuntu. Java and Eclipse are installed and working fine. When I install Accurev, I got the following error:

```
Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file

Launching installer...

./AccuRev_5_4_1_LinuxClientOnly_x86_2_4.bin: 3310: exec: /tmp/install.dir.2907/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: not found
```

anybody can help me?  thanks

**EDIT:**

Answers below plus asnswer [here](http://www.accurev.com/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php/topics/3812/cannot_install_Accurev5_4_1_on#Post3812), or http://www.accurev.com/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php/topics/3812/cannot_install_Accurev5_4_1_on#Post3812

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [this site](http://waoewaoe.wordpress.com/) you have the solution, and I've seen that same problem before with other software, with other linux:

You have to create a symbolic link to /lib/libc.so.6. Do that:

> 1. Locate the file
>
>    locate libc.so.6
> 2. Create a symbolic link
>
>    ln -s /path/to/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6

Comment: Or a one liner if you're feeling lucky: `sudo ln -s \`locate libc.so.6\` /lib/libc.so.6`

Answer (score 13):

**A quick solution.**

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands:

For 64-bit Ubuntu (17.10 or newer):

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

For 64-bit Ubuntu (before 17.10):

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/libc.so.6
```

For 32-bit Ubuntu (before 17.10):

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: in Kubuntu 14.04 there is no `/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but there is `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: Thanks, improved answer based on your suggestion.